# python3: How to do find and replace in a list with a regex?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a python list. In which, the word "cat" existing two times.

`['cat', 'rat', 'bat', 'vat', 'cat']`

I want to replace "the last word cat" with 'fat'. The final result should be

`['cat', 'rat', 'bat', 'vat', 'fat']`

.
How can i replace "the last word cat"?

**The example code:-**

```
list3 = ['cat', 'rat', 'bat', 'vat', 'cat']
theLast= list3[-1]
print(theLast)
```

Comment: You want to replace the last occurence of the word `"cat"` with `"fat"`? Why do you need regex for this?

Comment: To denote the position( -1), i want to use regex.($)

Comment: Regex works on strings but the example you gave is of a list. Why do you want to use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
list3 = ['cat', 'rat', 'bat', 'vat', 'cat']
list3[-1] = "fat"
```

list_name[-1] is the last element in the list regardless of it's value.
in your example `list3[-1]` is the last element in the list `list3 "cat"`.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
print(list1[-1]) #output: 3
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(list2[-1]) #output: "c"
```

Comment: sorry. i confused. $ Dollar sign denotes last position in regex. The last word vary from list to list. so i want to use $ Dollar sign to do replace instead of the last word.

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer and let me know if that helps

Comment: // list3[-1] = "fat" // then how to print the new list?

Comment: like you would print the old one print(list3)

Comment: @info-farmer take a look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_lists.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing:

```
list3 =                   ['cat', 'rat', 'bat', 'vat', 'cat']
#                           |      |      |      |      |
#Clockwise index -->        0      1      2      3      4   
#Anticlockwise Index -->    0     -4     -3     -2     -1

list3[-1] = "fat"
```

Here, index of first 'cat' = 0 and if you traverse anticlockwise in the list then the index of last 'cat' will be -1.